# How to affect a string to a variable without redefining it

Tags: php

I'm working on a project, and it has a bunch of variables for some links that I define. But I want to add a string at the end of those variable only if I got some GET parameters. The thing is I don't want to have another huge amount of variables and I want to have the same name for the variables. After some research, I came with this operator `.=` which is perfect for me. I also made a `for loop` it works well for the variable value, but I don't have the same name.

Here is what I got:

```php
$homeLink = $wURL.'government/'.$job.'/';
$databaseLink = $wURL.'government/'.$job.'/search/database';
$overviewLink = $wURL.'government/'.$job.'/overview';

// Other variables

if (!isset($_SESSION['steamid']) && isset($_GET['uID']) && isset($_GET['uToken'])) {
  // redefine the variables like this:
  $homeLink .= '?uID='.$userinfoVlife['id'].'&uToken='.$userinfoVlife['websiteMDP'];
  /* 
   OUTPUT: $wURL.'government/'.$job.'/'.'?uID='.$userinfoVlife['id'].'&uToken='.$userinfoVlife['websiteMDP']
  */

  // The for loop:
    $arr = array($homeLink,$databaseLink,$overviewLink);
    $nb = count($arr);
    for ($i=0; $i < $nb ; $i++) {
      $arr[$i] .= '?uID='.$userinfoVlife['id'].'&uToken='.$userinfoVlife['websiteMDP'];
      echo $arr[$i]."<br>";
     // have the same output that above but I have to call my variables with $arr[<a number>];
    }
}
```

The thing is **I don't want to have another huge amount of variables** and **I want to have the same name for the variables**, any ideas on how I can proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your 2 last links are actually both based on the first one, `$homeLink`:

```php
$homeLink = $wURL.'government/'.$job.'/';
$databaseLink = $homeLink.'search/database';
$overviewLink = $homeLink.'overview';
```

then why not build the parameter string and then append it?

```php
$homeLink = $wURL.'government/'.$job.'/'

$paramString = '';
if (!isset($_SESSION['steamid']) && isset($_GET['uID']) && isset($_GET['uToken'])) {
    $paramString = '?uID='.$userinfoVlife['id'].'&uToken='.$userinfoVlife['websiteMDP'];
}


$databaseLink = $homeLink.'search/database'.$paramString;
$overviewLink = $homeLink.'overview'.$paramString;
$homeLink .= $paramString;
```

I don't get why you want to store your URLs in an array, these are different URLs, thus to be used in different contexts, having all of them in one array is of course possible but doesn't bring any value, in my opinion.

To conclude, if `$userinfoVlife['websiteMDP']` contains a readable password, you definitely have a problem in your application architecture: it's very bad practice to handle raw passwords and it's even worse to pass it in the URL.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I didn't thought about that, it's in fact very simple! 
For the array, it was just a test, for the **for** loop, and for the `$userinfoVlife['websiteMDP']` it's in fact linked to another database, and is refreshed every connection that the user do *(it doesn't provides any access, it's just for me to fetch users across the database)*.